# Comparing two array and combining them with condition

Tags: matlab

I have these matrices:

```
I1 = [60    30    15    35    20   -25    30     5    45    25   -10    40    10];
I2 = [60    30    60    35    20    60    30    60    45    25    60    40    60];
A= 0:12 ;
```

I want this:

```
Ir=[60 30 15 NaN 60 35 20 -25  NaN  60 30  5 NaN 60 45 25 -10 NaN  60  40  10 NaN 60]
Ar= [0  1  2  2   2  3  4   5   5    5  6  7  7   7  8  9  10  10  10  11  12  12 12]
```

How:
When `I1` and `I2` are same, proceed. When different, use elements of both `I1` and `I2` and insert an NaN between them.

and `Ar` is such that use element of `A` and proceed when elements of `I1` and `I2` are same. But when different, repeat the value of `A` 3 times. 1st for `I1` and then for `NaN` and then for `I2`.

Can't figure out a way to do this. How do I do this?

Comment: Take a look at the [`ismember`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) function. This makes the generation of `Ir` possible in one short line of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more vectorized way to do this would be to create an augmented matrix where the top row is `I1`, the bottom row is `I2` and the middle row is full of `NaN`.  After, create a `logical` matrix which is the same size as this augmented matrix you just created and you would adjust the columns of this matrix where you'd set the bottom two rows of this `logical` matrix to 0 for each corresponding column in this matrix where `I1 == I2`.  Once you're done, use this `logical` matrix and index the augmented matrix.  The advantage of this indexing is that it accesses the elements in column major format, which is exactly what you're after.  We will only sample the top row of the augmented matrix unless the elements in `I1` and `I2` don't equal each other.  If that's the case, we sample the entire column which includes both `I1`, `nan` and `I2`.  Because we accessed by columns, your desired output is a row so you'll need to transpose the result when you're done.

To create the index vector, you would do the same thing but you would create a matrix of IDs where we have three rows where each row is the index ID array `A`.  You'll also need to transpose this result after you index into `A`:

```
aug = [I1; nan(1,numel(I1)); I2];
V = true(size(aug));
V(2:3, I1 == I2) = false;
Ir = aug(V).';
ID = repmat(A, 3, 1);
Ar = ID(V).';
```

We get:

```
>> format compact
>> Ir
Ir =
  Columns 1 through 17
    60    30    15   NaN    60    35    20   -25   NaN    60    30     5   NaN    60    45    25   -10
  Columns 18 through 23
   NaN    60    40    10   NaN    60
>> Ar
Ar =
  Columns 1 through 17
     0     1     2     2     2     3     4     5     5     5     6     7     7     7     8     9    10
  Columns 18 through 23
    10    10    11    12    12    12
```

Comment: @EkEhsaas OK, it looks like you can upvote now.  You have > 15 rep.  Thanks for the accept, you are very welcome and good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I can provide you with pseudo-code.

```
for each value in A
  if I1 at [current A value] equals I2 at [current A value]
    add I1 at [current A value] to end of Ir 
    add [current A value] to end of Ar
  else
    add I1 at [current A value] to end of Ir
    add NaN to Ir
    add I2 at [current A value] to end of Ir
    add [current A value] to Ar 3 times
```

If your problem was conceptual hopefully this is enough.
Let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two indices and solve the problem. The first index `ii` goes over the input vectors, and the second index `k` grows as the computation proceeds. A simple code using `for-loop` and `if-statement` looks like this:

```
I1 = [60    30    15    35    20   -25    30     5    45    25   -10    40    10];
I2 = [60    30    60    35    20    60    30    60    45    25    60    40    60];
Ir = [];
Ar = [];
k = 1;
for ii=1:length(I1)
    if I1(ii)==I2(ii)
        Ir(k) = I1(ii);
        Ar(k) = ii-1;
        k = k + 1;
    else
        Ir(k:k+2) = [I1(ii) NaN I2(ii)];
        Ar(k:k+2) = ii-1;
        k = k + 3;
    end
end
```

Will result in:

```
Ir =

    60    30    15   NaN    60    35    20   -25   NaN    60    30     5   NaN    60    45    25   -10   NaN    60    40    10   NaN    60


Ar =

     0     1     2     2     2     3     4     5     5     5     6     7     7     7     8     9    10    10    10    11    12    12    12
```

Comment: I appreciate that. But i heard that it is bad to grow size. and there is more problem that Ar is not just anything starting from zero. it can be anything like `0 5 6 4 2...` I wrote 0:12 for simple. and Ar is depending on A :(